# ¿Cómo actualizar lista con múltiples valores?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando crear una lista con los valores que recibo de las fechas, esto funciona perfectamente con `dt_3` pero tengo que repetir el proceso para `dt_1`, `dt_7`, `dt_31`. ¿Cómo puedo simplificar este proceso de generar la lista y luego pasársela a `start_urls`?.

```
plantilla = ("https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear={año_devolucion}&doFiltering=true"
            "&fromLocChoose=true&filterTo=49&dropLocationName={localidad}&ftsType=C&ftsLocationSearch={codigoLocalidad}"
            "&dropFtsSearch=L&doDay={dia_devolucion}&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth={mes_solicitud}&dropFtsInput={localidad}&dropCountry=Argentina"
            "&puDay={dia_solicitud}&dropFtsLocationSearch={codigoLocalidad}&puHour=10&dropFtsEntry=22776&enabler=&distance=10"
            "&ftsEntry=22776&city={localidad}&driverage=on&filterName=CarCategorisationSupplierFilter&dropCity={localidad}"
            "&dropFtsType=C&ftsAutocomplete={localidad}+Argentina&driversAge=30&dropFtsAutocomplete={localidad}+Argentina"
            "&dropFtsLocationName={localidad}&dropCountryCode=&doMinute=0&countryCode=&puYear={año_solicitud}&locationName=&puMinute=0&ftsInput={localidad}"
            "&coordinates={cordenadas}&dropLocation={codigoLocalidad}&doHour=10&dropCoordinates={cordenadas}" 
            "&ftsLocationName={localidad}&ftsSearch=L&location={codigoLocalidad}&doMonth={mes_devolucion}&reducedCategory=medium&filterAdditionalInfo=&advSearch=&exSuppliers=&ordering=price")

    casos = [{"localidad":"Salta",
            "codigoLocalidad": "161",
            "cordenadas":"-24.7833%2C-65.4167"},
            {"localidad":"Mendoza",
            "codigoLocalidad": "106",
            "cordenadas":"-32.889%2c-68.843"},
            {"localidad":"San+Carlos+de+Bariloche",
            "codigoLocalidad": "-1",
            "cordenadas":"-41.1335%2C-71.3102"},
            {"localidad":"Tucum%C3%A1n",
            "codigoLocalidad": "-1",
            "cordenadas":"-26.5917%2C-65.5833"},
            {"localidad":"Neuqu%C3%A9n",
            "codigoLocalidad": "111",
            "cordenadas":"-38.95%2C-68.0667"},
            {"localidad":"Buenos+Aires",
            "codigoLocalidad": "51",
            "cordenadas":"-34.6038%2C-58.3816"},
            {"localidad":"C%C3%B3rdoba",
            "codigoLocalidad": "61",
            "cordenadas":"-31.4166%2C-64.1837"}]


    dias_Semana = date.today() + timedelta(7)

    dt_1 = dias_Semana + timedelta(1)
    dt_3 = dias_Semana + timedelta(3)
    dt_7 = dias_Semana + timedelta(7)
    dt_31 = dias_Semana + timedelta(31)

    start_urls = []

    for datos in casos:

        datos.update({"año_devolucion": dt_3.year,"dia_devolucion": dt_3.day,"mes_solicitud":dias_Semana.month ,"dia_solicitud": dias_Semana.day,"año_solicitud":dias_Semana.year,"mes_devolucion":dt_3.month})

        start_urls.append(plantilla.format(**datos))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas construir una lista para luego iterar por los elementos de esta:

```
dias_Semana = date.today() + timedelta(7)
fechas = [
    dias_Semana + timedelta(1),
    dias_Semana + timedelta(3),
    dias_Semana + timedelta(7),
    dias_Semana + timedelta(31)
]

start_urls = []
for fecha in fechas:
     for datos in casos:
        datos.update({"año_devolucion": fecha.year,"dia_devolucion": fecha.day,"mes_solicitud":dias_Semana.month ,"dia_solicitud": dias_Semana.day,"año_solicitud":dias_Semana.year,"mes_devolucion":fecha.month})
        start_urls.append(plantilla.format(**datos))
```

`fecha` es el elemento individual de cada iteración y lo usas como cualquier variable. Eventualmente podría serte útil que la lista final contenga la fecha.

```
start_urls.append((fecha, plantilla.format(**datos)))
```

En este caso la lista `start_urls` contendrá tuplas, dónde el primer elemento será la `fecha` y el segundo las urls.